# how can i post form object, correctly?

Tags: python, django, django-views

i am practicing CBV , so i thought to check if i can override methodes, well one of biggest problems is that idk how to use data(like data just submitted ), i wrote this code for a `DetailView` so i could see post and comments under it:

```
class ArtDetailView(FormView, DetailView):
    model = Art
    form_class = CommentForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ArtDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['time'] = timezone.now()
        context['form'] = self.get_form()
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.writer = self.request.user
        form.instance.text = self.post
        #form.instance.art = Art.objects.get(id=self.pk)
        form.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)


    def get_success_url(self) -> str:
        return reverse('pages:art_detail', args=(self.kwargs['pk'],))
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms

from .models import Art, Comment

class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = Comment
        fields = ['text','art']
```

but when i post something it is in this shape:[screen_shot(2nd comment)](https://i.postimg.cc/J4SWxW3Y/Screenshot-51.png)
,i think problem is with`form.instance.text = self.post` but i don't know how to fix it
can you please also explain a little because all i want is to learn.
and i tried to also add `art` as autofill(i added as comment) but wasn't successful, can you pls check it it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can overide post method to save form as well. Since you only adding form which is always a text and no possible errors in forms unless blank. You code snippet will look like this

```
# In forms.py
def CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('text', )
# In views.py
class ArtDetailView(FormView, DetailView):
    # same as previous but remove form_valid method
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form_instance = form.save(commit=False)
            # this will give form instance and then add related field and save again (commit=True by default)
            form_instance.writer = request.user
            # since it is art detail view, self.get_object() will give art object
            form_instance.art = self.get_object()
            form_instance.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
        else:
            return super().form_invalid(from)
```

If you go to FormView declaration you will find like this
[image]

Comment: thank you, also for resource code ,it seems helpful to learn CBV

Comment: also can i ask how should i recognize which method should i use, like i thought if i use ```form_valid``` it will be okay , like you did , saving form in ```form_valid()```

Comment: If you dive deep into documentation, the FormView which only says """A view for displaying a form and rendering a template response.""" and again from parent class of FormView which is FormMixin has fomr_valid() which only return success url. You have to implement your own logic to save form. If you want to save form on form_valid() you should look into `ModelFormMixin`

Comment: i never took it this serious , thanks